# Weibull parameters as a function of values of the c.d.f.

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$: The waiting time between two earthquakes (in years). We know that $X$ is following a Weibull distribution, i.e. $X \sim W(\gamma=0, \beta, \delta)$. How can I find $\beta$ and $\sigma$ knowing that $P(X>15) = 0.3679$ and $P(X\leq 5) = 0.2835$.

I found the system of equation $-15\beta - \log(0.3679)\delta = 0$ and $-5 \beta - \log(0.7125)\delta = 0$, but it means $\beta = \delta = 0$. The answer is $\beta > 2$ and $\delta < 16$. How is that possible?

**EDIT:**

The Weibull distribution is defined as

$$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x < \gamma \\
1 - \exp\left[ - \left( \frac{x-\gamma}{\delta} \right)^\beta \right], & \text{if } x \geq \gamma
\end{cases}$$

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\exp\left[ - \left( \frac 5 \delta \right)^\beta \right] & = 1-0.2835 = 0.7165 \\ {} \\
\exp\left[ - \left( \frac {15}\delta \right)^\beta \right] & = 0.3679
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
& \left( \frac 5 \delta \right)^\beta = - \log 0.7165 \\ {} \\
& \left( \frac{15} \delta \right)^\beta = -\log 0.3679
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
& \beta\log5-\beta\log\delta = \log(-\log 0.7165) \\ {} \\
& \beta\log15-\beta\log\delta = \log(-\log 0.3679)
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting, we get
$$
\beta\log3 = \log(-\log 0.3679) - \log(-\log 0.7165)
$$

Comment: Then
$$
\beta = \frac{\log(-\log 0.3679) - \log(-\log 0.7165)}{\log3} = \cdots
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy You should put it to build a full answer. You put it to build a comment instead. Just saying ;)

Comment: I would have done that if there had not still been some questions in my mind about this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Never too late to change it ;)

Comment: Possibly I'll look at this further later.